# Is this an appropriate use of DI factories?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory

I have inherited the following code in an ASP.NET application that registers its classes on the default service container:

```cs
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
  serviceCollection.AddTransient<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
  serviceCollection.AddTransient(p => p.GetService<IConfigService>().GetConfigFromDb());
}
```

The `GetConfigFromDb()` method tries to get various context-dependent configuration values via multiple sequential queries to a separate physical database server (potentially in another datacenter). Later these values are used via constructor injection in a handful of services that look like this:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
  private Configs config;

  public SomeService(Configs configs)
  {
    this.configs = configs;
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     //doing something with configs.SomeValue
  }
}
```

Intuitively I would have tried to avoid the use of the service locator and would have moved the work done in `GetConfigFromDb()` away from the service container altogether like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
  serviceCollection.AddTransient<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
}
```

Then I would have called the method in the service that actually uses it:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
  private Configs config;

  public SomeService(IConfigService configService)
  {
    this.configs = configService.GetConfigFromDb();
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     //doing something with configs.SomeValue
  }
}
```

This seems to align better with the [recommendation in Microsofts Dependency injection guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#recommendations) to *Keep DI factories fast and synchronous*. However, these recommendations seem to focus more on the sync/async aspect and the potential deadlocks that could result from this. Also I am not sure what *fast* means in this context.

My questions are:

1. Are there clear advantages or disadvantages of one approach over the other? Does it matter at all?
2. Are there any reputable sources on best practices around DI factories like this (as I was not able to find anything beyond the linked guidelines)?
3. Are there examples of public code where DI factories are used? I haven't encountered them before and I am trying to get an understanding of common use cases for them.

Comment: I think this is going to be opinion-based, but mine aligns with yours, if I read you correctly: the factory should just create simple instances, not execute other complex logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ease your mind, a callback to the container from within your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) is *not* an implementation of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). This means that the following code sample from your question does not exhibit the Service Locator pattern:

> ```
> serviceCollection.AddTransient(
>     p => p.GetService<IConfigService>().GetConfigFromDb());
> ```

Calling `p.GetService<T>()` inside a registration is not a bad practice, because you are doing so in a part of your code base that has intrinsic knowledge about the existence of that particular DI Container. As a matter of fact, with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI), many types of registrations are simply impossible to make without calling back into the container from inside a registration lambda.

This doesn't necessarily mean, however, that the registration `p.GetService<IConfigService>().GetConfigFromDb()` is a good idea. I would argue it isn't, but that's not because of the call to `GetService<T>()`, but because you are actually calling a service during the composition phase. i.e. you are calling `GetConfigFromDb()` while your classes are being created by the container.

The call to `GetConfigFromDb()` does, as you yourself mention, "queries to a separate physical database server." This is I/O and any operation that can fail should be moved out of the composition process, because it "complicates the Composition Root with an extra responsibility, and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration." ([source](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/))

Unfortunately, the same holds when you are using a service within the constructor of a consumer, as you are doing in your second attempt:

> ```
>  public SomeService(IConfigService configService)
>  {
>    this.configs = configService.GetConfigFromDb();
>  }
> ```

This still causes problems because you are still using the `IConfigService` during object composition. Instead strive to have constructors that are [simple and fast](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) in such way that you can [compose object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

> Are there clear advantages or disadvantages of one approach over the other? Does it matter at all?

Both have severe disadvantages, which is why you should keep object composition free of doing any I/O. This means you either load this config before starting to resolve any services from the container, or you load the config lazily. I'll show examples of both solutions.

#### Solution 1: Load config before resolving services

What you can do is the following:

```cs
// Pull in the config once at startup
var service = new ConfigService(...);
var config = service.GetConfigFromDb();

// Only after that start registrering services
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton(config);
...
```

With this approach, `ConfigService` is created outside the context of the DI Container. This might be a problem in case `ConfigService` has (many) dependencies of its own. You can, therefore, also initialize the config more lazily as follows:

```cs
public interface IConfigProvider
{
    Configs Configs { get; }
}

public sealed class LazyLoadingConfigProvider : IConfigProvider
{
    private readonly IConfigService configService;

    private Configs configs;

    public InitializableConfigProvider(IConfigService configService) =>
       this.configService = configService;

    public Configs Configs =>
        this.configs ?? (this.configs = this.configService.GetConfigFromDb());
}

public class SomeService // Now depends on IConfigProvider instead
{
  private readonly IConfigProvider provider;

  public SomeService(IConfigProvider provider)
  {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     var configs = this.provider.Configs;
     //doing something with configs.SomeValue
  }
}
```

```cs
// Register services
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
services.AddSingleton<IConfigProvider, LazyLoadingConfigProvider>();
services.AddTransient<SomeService>();

// Later on, when the container is created, but before the first request comes in:
// provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

// Eager load the configs from the database
_ = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfigProvider>().Configs;
```

Both options separate the loading of any required config from the container registration process. Downside this is that the config is loaded just once (which might be a problem for a long-running application) and the value is required at startup. This is when solution 2 comes in.

#### Solution 2: Load the config lazily

With the previous solution, you already saw a new `IConfigProvider` interface. Such interface is important when it comes to accessing runtime data. In this solution use that interface as well, because such interface gives us freedom to choose the way we load that data, without the consumer to be aware of this.

You can imagine a solution where you do exactly the same as in option 2 of the previous solution, but now without eagerly loading the config. That means that the very first call to `SomeService.SomeMethod` will load the config from the database.

This still makes the the config a singleton, though, which might not fit your requirements. In that case you could, for instance, simply make the registration for `LazyLoadingConfigProvider` scoped:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IConfigProvider, LazyLoadingConfigProvider>();
```

This allows every new request to pull in the latest configs from the database once.

From this point on, however, it might get fairly complicated, because if you have 50 requests per second, it means pulling in the config 50 times a second. If one of those config pulls fails, the complete request fails. It would be fairly unlikely that a config changes at that rate, so you likely want to implement some caching strategy on the loading on the config and what to do when loading fails. For instance, you could serve an 'old' config for as long as loading the configs fail. And you might want to synchronize loading the new configs to prevent having many simultaneous calls to the config database server. All this clever synchronization and cachiness could be implemented within the `IConfigProvider` implementation.

Considering the amount of text already in my answer, I would like to keep implementing such cache as an exercise for the reader.

> Are there any reputable sources on best practices around DI factories like this (as I was not able to find anything beyond the linked guidelines)?

I think I already linked a few, here are they again:

- [Understanding the Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) — an excerpt from [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://cuttingedge.it/book) (DIPP&P), a book written by [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk/about/) and [me](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/about/)
- [The Service Locator Anti-Pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) — from DIPP&P as well
- [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) — by me.
- [Injection Constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) — by Mark Seemann
- [Compose object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/) — by Mark Seemann

I'll leave it up to the reader to decide whether the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://cuttingedge.it/book) and its authors (Mark Seemann and I) are "reputable sources."